# android layout on different screen sizes

Tags: android, layout

i have an application that am trying to implement it on a tablet 7'. this that i have done is the follow. on the folder drawable and layout are my defaults for the normal smartphone screen. also i have create the layout-xlarge and drawable-mdpi in which on the first one i have change the sizes and on the second one i add the images with different size. my problem is that the default get the size of images that i have on the drawable-mdpi folder and not from the default drawable folder. what am i doing wrong? also i have nothing declare on the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mdpi is the default, so drawable and drawable-mdpi are the same thing and I don't know which Android chooses in this case - but you're designing for a tablet and tablets are generally mdpi devices so it correctly gets it from drawable-mdpi. You could use drawable-xlarge-mdpi if you want separate mdpi resources to be used for extra-large screens. Incidentally, remember a 7" 1024x600 tablet is large, not xlarge - so try drawable-large-mdpi and layout-large-mdpi and see if that gives you what you want.

Comment: ok i din't know that the default was the mdpi. i will work on this in order to fix the icons and the layout. thanks